# Add item in array react hooks and access them

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, formik, formik-material-ui

I am trying to add an item in an array and I access them with the `onChange()` in the dropdown but it's not being saved below is my source :

```
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState<string[]>([]);

const handleChange = useCallback( (event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
const { value } = event.target;
if (value){
  setSelectedValue([...selectedValue, value]);
  setFieldValue('company.data.organisation', value);
  console.log('---', selectedValue)
}
```

},[setSelectedValue, selectedValue]);

Then I access the `onChange()` on the dropdown as below :

```
           <Field
                onChange={handleChange}
                component={TextField}
                select
                fullWidth
                size="small"
                variant="outlined"
                name="company.data.organisation">
                { selectedValue.length > 0 ? selectedValue.map(name => (
                <MenuItem value={name} key={`company-data-${name}`}>
                  {name}
                </MenuItem>
              )):
              chosenLegalForm.cooperation_form.map(({ value, name }) => (
                <MenuItem value={value} key={`company-data-${value}`}>
                  {name}
                </MenuItem>
              ))
            }
              </Field>
```

Comment: is the field supposed to be populated with the same array that you're adding to?

Comment: @SamPetering, it's an empty array and I want to add only new items.

Comment: What dependencies did you pass to your useCallback?

Comment: Right but you're mapping your selectedValue array into the field component, is that intentional?

Comment: I have updated , the dependencies are available

Comment: I mapping the selectedValue since its an array , so I am mapping all items into a drpdown

Comment: but it looks like you're also trying to add the value from the field to that array when you select it...

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I wanted to minimize code, but the dropdown has some items, however, when I select one item, I want to store it in another list , and I show the new list , I have updated again my code

Comment: So by default `chosenLegalForm.cooperation_form` has some data populating the dropdown

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-architecture-1othh?file=/src/App.js here's a working example if that helps

Comment: @LPT0, thanks for sharing , but on my ned still having same issues, it's not saving in typescript wondering why

Comment: Surprising in the `useState` its printing    ```useEffect(() => {
    console.log('check ',selectedValue)
  },[selectedValue]);```

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-architecture-1othh?file=/src/App.tsx You'll figure it out

Comment: Thanks , it finally worked